# JavaScript not detecting change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this is easy but I've looked all over with no luck. I have written a paging jQuery script that animates a list on my page. I have next and previous buttons which I am showing/hiding depending on where you are in the list however it doesnt pick up the position change the first time. Here is my code in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mikeoram/t4787/

I'm sure I'm only missing something simple, all suggestions would be helpful.

Please only answer my question, there are reasons I'm doing it the way I am, and i no it can be done differently.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: could you post your HTML code?

Comment: Please, post some HTML or make a http://jsfiddle.net. This easy our life and helps to answer faster.

Comment: _"Please only answer my question, there are reasons I'm doing it the way I am, and no it can't be done different."_ That sounds pretty demanding and not a great attitude towards people only trying to help.  Also, your question stays here to help others in the future, so any suggestions towards improvement goes way beyond _your_ immediate needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `top` is a reserved variable that refers to the top window in the hierarchy. Always declare the variables inside functions so it doesn't mess with the rest of your code:

```
var top = $('.paginate').css('top');
```

Second, use regex to remove the non digits from the top value, so it will always be a valid integer:

See this http://jsfiddle.net/MaLDK/1/

Comment: thanks for the help, iv made your amends however it still hasnt fixed my issue. please see the example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeoram/t4787/

Comment: Also note that I've moved the `buttons()` call directly to the callback of the `animate()` call, so it executes as soon as the animation ends. Also, the comparison has to be as string: `top == "0"`, as your `top` variable is a string.

Comment: ahhh brilliant! thank you very much! For anyone reading this post the answer to the problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/t4787/1/ Notice the button check needs to be put as the last value inside animate() so that it is executed when the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.paginate').css('top');` can return you `0px`

If you want to compare numbers do `parseFloat( $('.paginate').css('top') );`

This will remove non-digits at the end of any string, if there are no characters before the numbers.

Comment: thanks for the help but yes i no it returns with the px on the value which is why I was removing the last two characters. and so no need for parseFloat. Thanks for the suggestion though.